# Add file extension from grep count

Tags: bash, file, grep

I have a large set of files (about 10k) with filenames starting with `prefix`. They do not have any extension. I would like to given them a numerical extension that corresponds to the number of lines in each that contain a certain `string`. I know how to use grep to find this number:

```
grep -c string *
```

This outputs (extract)

```
prefix0123:1
prefix9876:5
```

What I want is to add the counts as extensions, i.e., obtain

```
prefix0123.1
prefix9876.5
```

I am working in a bash console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run your `grep` command once for each file, and substitute its output directly into the new file name:

```
for i in *
do
  test -f "$i" || continue
  mv -nv "$i" "$i.$(grep -c string "$i")"
done
```

I've explicitly excluded non-regular files, as `grep` won't like a directory as argument (you could allow symlinks if you choose).  I've also added `-n` to the move command, so we don't accidentally overwrite any existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to generate to a `file:count` pair in `grep` by adding a using recursive search with `-r` flag and then re-naming it as

```
grep -cr bash * | while IFS=':' read -r file count; do
    mv -v "$file" "${file}.${count}"
done
```

You could replace `mv` with an `echo "$file" "${file}.${count}"` first to confirm if all your files are renamed as you *expect* it to be and then use the `mv` command.

Comment: Will this work if `*` matches exactly one file?  You might need to tell `grep` to always emit the filename - `grep -H` works for GNU grep.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Thanks for the suggestion. Will let the OP decide based on his output seen.

Comment: I prefer Toby Speight's solution, because it is clearer *to me* what is happening. I do not assume your solution does not have other advantages.